# Nemo - use keyboard to switch to different parts of the window?

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, nemo

I'm a mouse-hater... or more fairly, I hate being forced to use the mouse when a keyboard alternative should be possible.

With Nemo it's nice because you don't just have a filesystem navigator, you also get given a command line. But I can't find any way of getting from one to the other without using the mouse... anyone know if this is possible?

In things like FileExplore (Windoze) you can use tabbing and/or shift-tabbing (reverse order) and/or control-tabbing (escape upwards so you tab through the commands... or something)

Comment: anyone finding this topic, because of confusion about the "3-click" issue when switching from one panel to the other -- please see https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not well implemented, and very poorly documented.

I'm just a common-or-garden mouse-hater. But accessibility requires that users be able to do the absolute maximum possible without using mice.

another_nemo_user correctly identifies **F4** as the toggle of the top-pane-Terminal. BUT... THIS DOESN'T WORK WHEN YOU ARE INSIDE this pane! Instead you have to go **Ctrl-L first** (focus to breadcrumbs) and **then F4**.

Apart from that you have to **Tab** to get from breadcrumbs to the left-hand listing pane, **Shift-F6** to get from there to the main (current directory) listing pane, and **F6** to get from there to the left-hand listing pane.

Improvements: there should be a single hotkey command which traverses all visible panes in order and its shift- counterpart to traverse in reverse order... and another toggle key to move focus to/from the menu bar. This is the convention... and it is there for a good reason.

Answer (score 4):

Searching the same answer, I found:
[82 Shortcuts for Linux Mint (including Nemo)](https://shortcutworld.com/Linux-Mint/linux/Linux-Mint_Shortcuts)

Where you can find shortcuts like:

### Panes

- <kbd>F3</kbd>: Toggle Extra Pane (split view that shows two folder side by side)
- <kbd>F4</kbd>: Toggle Terminal in top pane (require the Nemo Terminal plugin)
- <kbd>F6</kbd>: Cycle focus between panes
- <kbd>F9</kbd>: Toggle left pane (browsing folders only)
- <kbd>F8</kbd>, then <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>: Resize panes.

  > Press F8 to cycle through the separators between panes (the selected
  > one will be highlighted).
  > Then use the arrow keys to resize the
  > separator.
- also bookmarks, and more...

### Tabs

Browser-like:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: New tab in current pane
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Previous tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Down</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Next tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Up</kbd> / <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>: Move tab left / right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Close tab

### Folders

Some classical shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>: Previous browsed directory
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>: Next browsed dir.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>: Parent dir.

### And many more, as seen in link title!

Happy keyboarding!

Comment: Thanks, useful link. So from a couple of mins of experimenting it appears that you can move focus from the directory listing to the terminal window at the top by F6. But getting back out of that terminal window is not obvious. You can do Ctrl-L to put the focus in the breadcrumbs bar, and then F4 to hide the terminal window... then I'm stuck.  Odd.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, having gone Ctrl-L to escape the terminal-screen, Tab to get the left-hand side listing... and then Shift-F6 to get to the directory contents listing (F6 to switch back to the left-hand side listing). F4 to unhide the terminal-screen (and put focus in it).  The F4 toggle is therefore your best friend with this. But scandalously doesn't actually work when focus is in the terminal-screen. Grrrrr.